# Quoting pb with the Perl print function

Tags: bash, perl, printf, quoting

I want to `grep` a paragraph in a list a files using 2 regexp which are inside 2 bash variables, here is what I type :

```sh
$ startRegExp=function.toto
$ endRegExp=^}
$ set -x
$ perl -ne "print '\$ARGV:\$_' if /$startRegExp/ ... /$endRegExp/" .bash_functions*
```

But this is what I get :

```sh
+ perl -ne 'print '\''$ARGV:$_'\'' if /function.locate/ ... /^}/' .bash_functions .bash_functions.AV .bash_functions.Darwin .bash_functions.Debian .bash_functions.Linux .bash_functions.build .bash_functions.mpv .bash_functions.ytdl
$ARGV:$_$ARGV:$_$ARGV:$_$ARGV:$_$ARGV:$_$ARGV:$_$ARGV:$_$ARGV:$_$ARGV:$_$ARGV:$_$ARGV:$_$ARGV:$_$ARGV:$_$ARGV:$_
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes in Perl don't interpolate variables. Send the variables to the script through the environment so they become first class citizens and you can use any characters in them:

```
s=$startRegExp e=$endRegExp perl -ne 'print "$ARGV:$_" if /$ENV{s}/ ... /$ENV{e}/'
```

Note that if the file doesn't contain the closing `}`, perl will continue printing the next file. This can be fixed by changing the right range operand to `(/$ENV{e}/ || eof)`.

Comment: I'd argue that the environment approach is sufficiently stronger that it should probably be first, if not the *only* approach shown. Otherwise, anyone who can control your start and end regexps can inject arbitrary code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I agree, but surprisingly, the second approach is harder to explain to people not familiar with the details of the shell, environments, and Perl.

Comment: @choroba I chose the second approach because complicated quoting code is not easy for me to re-read.

Comment: @choroba BTW :Do you know what is wrong with my question that someone would want to close it ? I'd like to improve myself :)

Comment: The first solution suffers from a Code Injection bug! Don't generate Perl code from the shell! The correct answer being harder to explain doesn't justify explaining how to do it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

- Single-quotes don't interpolate. You need double-quoted strings, concatenation, etc.
- You are incorrectly generating Perl code. Generating code is hard to begin with, and doing it from the shell only makes it harder. You end up with all kinds of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bugs. Don't do this! Pass the data as arguments (or environment variables) instead.

Fixed:

```
perl -sne'print "$ARGV:$_" if /$s/.../$e/' -- \
   -s="$startRegExp" -e="$endRegExp" bash_functions*
```